# how get uploaded file from spring/ property folder

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, directory

I have Spring boot app, where I:

1. upload file
2. add file name to DB
3. want to show it in some page.
   For this:
4. In property file add

   upload.path= C:/spring/uploads/
5. Add this to

```
     public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        @Value("${upload.path}")
        private  String UPLOADED_FOLDER;
        
            @Override
            public void addResourceHandlers( ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addResourceHandler("/avatar/**", "/avatar/*", "/avatar/").addResourceLocations("file://" + UPLOADED_FOLDER + "/");
            }
```

3. .antMatchers("/avatar/**", in case to not block by security
4. try get image

I see added image in folder also name added to DB. Problem is that when I try add image to page it not shown and browser console show error 500.

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: C
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.doConnect(FtpClient.java:962) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.tryConnect(FtpClient.java:924) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:1019) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:1005) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.connect(FtpURLConnection.java:311) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(FtpURLConnection.java:417) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
```

It look like Spring couldn't recognize "/avatar/" folder us relative path.

P.S. In jar throw this exception:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'upload.path' in value "${upload.path}"

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in slash there should be 3 slashes.

.addResourceLocations("file:///" + UPLOADED_FOLDER + "/");